# How can I get permissions id of subrequest?

Tags: laravel

With spatie/laravel-permission I try to get Role and joined permissions id,
something like :

```
$role = Role
    ::getById($role_id)
    ->with('permissions')->pluck('id')
    ->first();
```

I do not get any error but     $role is invalid.

Can I do it, if yes in which way ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide more information? Are you trying to get $role ? Or permissionIds of a role?

Comment: permissionIds of a related role

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
App\Models\Role::where('id', $roleId)->with('permissions')->first()->permissions->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Here you can chain all permissionIds from Role or you can use:

```
App\Models\Role::where('id', $roleId)->first()->permissions->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks! But it could be only 2 requests(role and its permissions)? I mean is it impossible to make within 1 request?

Comment: your solution runs two queries to get the result, one when using `->first()` and the second when using `->permissions` then plucking from the collection instance the Ids.

Comment: @N69S so? It is already selected as an answer. The first result using "with" is the same with your answer. Which I answered before you.

Comment: @gguney the first result using "with" still runs two queries, the first query from `first()` and the second one from the eager loading using `with()`. it's not about who answer first or gets the "answer" score, it is for future readers to know that using `whereHas` will run only one query to get the same results and plucking on the query builder will result in a `select permissions.id from` query, wich is faster than plucking on a collection instance.

Answer (score 1):

To get the Role and the permissions associated to it

```
$role = App\Models\Role::where('id', $roleId)->with('permissions')->first();
$permissions = $role->permissions;

//if you only need the permissions without first getting the role (just with the role id) with only one query
$permissions = App\Models\Permission::whereHas('roles', function($roleQuery) use ($roleId) {
    $roleQuery->where('id', $roleId);
})->get();

//if you just need the list of ids of the role permissions with only one query
$permissionIds = App\Models\Permission::whereHas('roles', function($roleQuery) use ($roleId) {
    $roleQuery->where('id', $roleId);
})->pluck('id')->toArray();

//if you already have a $role instance (not just its ID)
$permissionIds = $role->permissions()->pluck('id')->toArray();

//if you only need the first permission id of a role switch pluck('id')->toArray() with ->value('id')
$firstPermissionId = $role->permissions()->value('id');
//or with only one query
$firstPermissionId = App\Models\Permission::whereHas('roles', function($roleQuery) use ($roleId) {
    $roleQuery->where('id', $roleId);
})->value('id');
```